# How do I prevent my php form from re-submitting on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, forms, oracle

I am using the following code for submitting a field in the database (using oracle), but upon successful submission of form if I refresh the form the form gets re-submitted. I am not using any session here.

Please help

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <?php
    $note=$_REQUEST['note'];
    $order = "INSERT INTO ec_note (nid, idno, note, flag, ec_date)
            VALUES
            (a_seq.nextval,'$id',
            '$note',1,sysdate)";
        if ($note)
        {
        $result = dbi_query($conn, $order); //order executes
        }
        if($result){
            echo("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>Your Note has been successfully uploaded
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
            </div>");
            }

    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="note" rows="15" placeholder="Maximum 4000 characters "></textarea> <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" onSubmit="window.location.reload()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add Note</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do a redirect after processing submitted data.

Comment: You reload before you submit Also NEVER call anything in a form `name=submit` . Change it if you need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Submit the form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="note" rows="15" placeholder="Maximum 4000 characters "></textarea> <br>
    <button type="submit" name="confirm" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add Note</button>
</form>
```

Now the problem is that if you reload the page you just POSTed, the POST will repeat. You then need this kind of page to *not* perform a reload. To do this you need the POSTed page to **never be shown in the browser**:

- you open the page (this is a GET)
- the page is displayed but not automatically posted
- you submit the page (this is a POST)
- *the page is fetched again via GET* <--
- the page is displayed but not automatically posted
- (repeat)

You achieve this by checking that there is a request, and if so, after performing the database insert, you redirect to the same page *without the POST*. This must be done before any output is sent to the browser, unless buffering is used:

```
$note=$_REQUEST['note'];
$order = "INSERT INTO ec_note (nid, idno, note, flag, ec_date)
    VALUES
    (a_seq.nextval,'$id',
    '$note',1,sysdate)";
if ($note)
{
    $result = dbi_query($conn, $order); //order executes, allowing SQL injection.
    // This reloads without allowing resubmit, unless button is pressed again
    // No other output must have been sent, or this WILL cause an error.
    die(Header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"));
}
```

**IMPORTANT**. You trust that the "note" field arrives by POST and does not contain anything bad. **This may not always be the case**.

So either use a query with prepared values, or use escaping to prevent `$_REQUEST['note']` from [summoning the dreaded Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

A better implementation:

```
if (isset($_POST)
    && array_key_exists('note', $_POST)
) {
    // I am not familiar with dbi_query. I suppose there exists a dbi_escape function?
    $note = YOUR_ESCAPE_FUNCTION($_POST['note'];)
    $order = "INSERT INTO ec_note (nid, idno, note, flag, ec_date)
    VALUES
    (a_seq.nextval,'$id',
    '$note',1,sysdate)";
    $result = dbi_query($conn, $order);

    // CHECK ERRORS AND DISPLAY THE APPROPRIATE RESPONSE

    // If no error, reload the form with a redirect and quit.
    // No output must have been sent to the browser up to now, or
    // this will cause an error.
    die(Header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"));
}
```